# Basin shapefile into HEC-HMS coordinate system issue

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, shapefile, hec-hms

I am trying to import a basin shapefile into HEC-HMS without going through with the whole HEC-GeoHMS process in an attempt to use HEC-HMS to calculate PMP values for the drainage area.

1. I make a new HEC-HMS file.
2. I set the units to US Customary.
3. I create a basin model.
4. I define the coordinate system for the basin model using the text provided in the ESRI .prj file.
5. I import the shapefile of my drainage area (same shapefile I pulled the .prj file text from.
6. I get the error "The coordinate system of the GIS file does not match the coordinate system of the basin model".

The goal is to use Vermont State Plane NAD83 Feet (2011) as the coordinate system. The shapefile was created / projected in ArcMap.

Below is the .prj file text I am trying to use. I was under the impression that this was the equivalent of WKT.

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_2011_StatePlane_Vermont_FIPS_4400_Ft_US",GEOGCS["GCS_NAD_1983_2011",DATUM["D_NAD_1983_2011",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",1640416.666666667],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-72.5],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999642857142857],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",42.5],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]
```

I have spent a fair bit of time trying to solve this issue trying other coordinate systems etc.. I am new to HEC-HMS and use GIS software for very specific purposes; by no means am I an expert user.

Answer (score 0):

Try developing all data in GIS and HMS using a .prj file downloaded from the following site https://spatialreference.org/. This solved a similar issue for me.

Comment: There's more than a couple of PRJ files on that site. Specifying which one would make this a much better answer.